# Where can I find documentation for "System Events"?

Tags: macos, applescript

Since "System Events" is the most commonly used application in AppleScript scripting, where can I find its documentation?

For example, it provides access to a window's contents with keyword "UI elements". Where can I find the full list of keywords that it supports?

Comment: Do you mean beyond opening its dictionary in Script Editor?

Comment: @KenThomases No that's what I'm looking for. I'll accept if you make this statement into an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the library for System Events in the Script Editor utility. That will show the terms of its scripting interface along with some basic reference documentation.

Comment: It might be useful to share how precisely to do this. E.G. in the Script Editor File menu, choose "Open Dictionary", choose "System Events" from the list.